# Short story or cartoon about a man who keeps buying new clocks and trying to synchonise them

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, cartoon

I don't remember if this is a short story or a cartoon. It would be mid-90s or older.

A man has clocks all over his house, and he keeps trying to synchronise them by checking the time on one clock, then going to the next room and changing the time on the next clock to be the same as the first clock, etc. Of course this is doomed to failure because of the time spent travelling between the clocks. I think he also keeps buying more and more clocks in an attempt to find out the correct time, until his whole house is just wall-to-wall clocks. But they all say a different time which really upsets the man. And the ding-dongs of the different clocks go off at different times.

I think at the end of the story, he travels somewhere to meet Father Time, who lives in a tower. And he might have to face a few challenges in order to get to meet him. And I think he is disappointed in some way, like Father Time isn't who he thought he was, or he isn't there, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

It’s called "[Clocks and More Clocks](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/296944.Clocks_and_More_Clocks)" by Pat Hutchins.

Comment: This would be a better answer (correct or not) if it included some information about the story that explains why you think it's the one the question asks about.  As it is, a one-liner answer with no support is likely to be deleted.

Comment: I don't think this is it. The illustrations have no ring of familiarity, and I am pretty sure it is a TV show. Thanks though!